# Link field values and ID to another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I link or add the field with all my users called "username" from my main table to another table so I can run checks and compare values without having to add a ton of rows to my main table? This would be a much cleaner and more organized setup.

Table called login_users. This is my main table that stores their basic information

```
username       email                 password
Anthony        user@email.com
Josh           user@email.com
Tsuyoshi       user@email.com
```

Table 2 called badge_status. This table will hold their status with whether or not they have unlocked an achievement on my site. I want to bring in the **usernames.**

```
username       badge1               badge2
Anthony        locked               unlocked
Josh           unlocked             locked
Tsuyoshi       unlocked             locked
```

Also, could table 2 automatically be updated with a new user when they sign up since all new sign ups are imported into the first table. As a side note, I am using phpmyadmin.

Thanks for any help with getting this set up. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should [normalize your data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) by using the following schema instead:

- login_users [Table]

  - username
  - email
  - password
- badges [Table]

  - BadgeId int PRIMARY KEY
  - BadgeName
  - ... *(any other relevant columns)*
- users_badges [Table]

  - username (foreign key constraint to username column on the `login_users` table)
  - BadgeId (foreign key constraint to BadgeId column on the `badges` table)

This will allow you add as many badges as you want without having to ever change your database schema or scripts.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand why you are separating out these tables. In theory, there is a one-to-one relationship between the two. Your query "could table 2 automatically be updated with a new user when they sign up since all new sign ups are imported into the first table" further supports the argument why *splitting these tables simply creates unnecessary overhead*.

Other sources of overhead include overly complicated JOINs to get the data out and the need to add an additional unique constraint on `badge_status.username` as well as a foreign key.

---

If you truly wish to separate out these tables, I would suggest the following setup instead which makes querying for specific badges and adding new badges very easy:

```
login_users: username, email, password, ...
badges: id, name, description, ...
users_badges: username, badge_id, status, unlocked_date, ...
```

Comment: Beat me to it. This is the way to go with a cross reference / composite table so that every use can have 0 to many badges. I would probably add a sort or order column to the badges table if you're going to be displaying a listing. You also may want to initialize inserts into the user_badges table on creation and default them to locked but both points are outside of the discussion.